# Get all unique combinations from two strings c#

Tags: c#, string

I am looking to get all unique combinations from two strings, for example:

```
STRING 1: "OK"
STRING 2: "OK"
```

Desire output

```
OKOK
KOOK
OKKO
KOKO
```

I couldn't find any useful information that can help me to get all unique combinations from two strings, only for one.

Two mentions: I would like to get some guidance using for loops and for strings with length more than 5 characters the output should be groups of 4 characters, two from each string.

```
STRING 1: "FOUR"
STRING 2: "FIVE"
```

Output

```
FOFI
OUIV
URVE
FOIV
OUVE
```

and so on until it gets to its maximum unique combinations.
Please consider that I did lot of research for this without any result.
Thanks.

My code so far

```
class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name");
        string name = "OK";
        Console.WriteLine("Lastname");
        string lastname = "OK";
        var nchars = name.ToCharArray();
        var pchars = lastname.ToCharArray();
        var ncharsCount = nchars.Length;
        var pcharsCount = pchars.Length;
            int ctr0;
            int ctr;
            int ctr2;
            for (ctr0 = 0; ctr0 < 1 ;ctr0++){
              for(ctr = 0; ctr<name.Length;ctr++){
                for(ctr2=1;ctr2<lastname.Length;ctr2++){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", ctr0,nchars[ctr%ncharsCount],nchars[ctr2%ncharsCount],pchars[ctr%pcharsCount],pchars[ctr2%pcharsCount]);
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

but my output right know is stopped at

```
OKOK
KKKK
```

which is incomplete and also invalid, considering that `KKKK` is impossible to achieve if we have a string `OK`.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: "I would like to get some guidance" **Guidance** or **ready code**? What did you try so far?

Comment: What about "OOKK" and "KKOO"?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It cannot be OOKK because two characters are coming from one string, and for example the first string does not have two O, it have O and K.

Comment: @LudovicFeltz, posted the current state of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split the initial task into smaller ones:

All `2` character fragments from given string:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SubStrings(string value, int length = 2) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    yield break;
  else if (length <= 0)
    yield break;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
      // modulo arithmetics to restart from the beginning e.g. "FOUR" -> "RF" 
      sb.Append(value[(i + j) % value.Length]); 

    yield return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Now we want a *cartesian join* of `SubStrings(string1)` and `SubStrings(string2)` which we can implement with a help of `SelectMany`:

```
 SubStrings(string1)
   .SelectMany(left => SubStrings(string2).Select(right => left + rigth));
```

Finally, let's add `Distinct`:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string string1 = "FOUR";
 string string2 = "FIVE";

 var result = SubStrings(string1)
   .SelectMany(left => SubStrings(string2).Select(right => left + right))
   .Distinct();

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome**

```
FOFI
FOIV
FOVE
FOEF
OUFI
OUIV
OUVE
OUEF
URFI
URIV
URVE
UREF
RFFI
RFIV
RFVE
RFEF
```

For `"OK"` and `"OK"` we have

```
OKOK
OKKO
KOOK
KOKO
```

**Edit:** *Linq* (`SelectMany`, `Distinct`) is very convenient when we query data. If you want, however, to get rid of it you have to put something like this:

```
// For Distinct, since HashSet contains unique values only
HashSet<string> result = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (string left in SubStrings(string1))
  foreach (string right in SubStrings(string2)) 
    result.Add(left + right);

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. One more quick question, considering that I am still learning, this is a bit hard for me to read, is there any possibility to get rid of IEnumerable  and .Select and replace them with for loops? maybe it is a stupid question but I am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: `Bogdan Darius` well, we can turn *cartesian join* into *nested loops*, but then we have to solve how to peek `Distinct` values only (you can exploit `HashSet<string>` for this). Please, see my edit

Comment: Thank you million times Dmitry, excellent explained, everything is so clear now. Nice job

Answer (score 1):

So you want all possible combinations of two characters from one string and two characters from the other.

When facing a problem like this, you could start with dividing your project into substeps:

- You'll probably need a method that provides all two-character combinations from a single string
- Another method would take *two* collections of two-character combinations, and combine them in all possible four-character combinations
- One method that orders a four-character combination in all possible ways
- And you'll probably want to remove all duplicate four-character combinations from that result

You don't have to follow my division of substeps, you can create your own - but this is the general approach I take when I'm overwhelmed by a problem. When stuck again, you'll have a much more specific question to ask on this site, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, this is the reason I came here, because I couldn't find anything useful, I do have this type of substeps in my mind.